# Cannot add foreign keys constraint

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE tblTransaction (
   strTransCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   dtmTransDate datetime,
   strTransDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   dblTransAmt double,
   intVoucRefCodeTrans INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (intVoucRefCodeTrans) REFERENCES tblVoucher (intVoucRefCode) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (strTransCode)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE tblVoucher (
   intVoucRefCode INT,
   strVoucRefDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   dtmVoucDate datetime,
   PRIMARY KEY (intVoucRefCode)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

these are my tables I don't know why it displays "Cannot add foreign key constraint" please help

Comment: change the order, one table needs to exist before the other..

Comment: thank you :)))))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

First create `tblVoucher` table then reference it in `tblTransaction` table

```
CREATE TABLE tblVoucher (
   intVoucRefCode INT,
   strVoucRefDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   dtmVoucDate datetime,
   PRIMARY KEY (intVoucRefCode)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tblTransaction (
   strTransCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   dtmTransDate datetime,
   strTransDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   dblTransAmt double,
   intVoucRefCodeTrans INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (intVoucRefCodeTrans) REFERENCES tblVoucher (intVoucRefCode) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (strTransCode)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/523e2)

Comment: be careful with wide PK's like you have in tblTransaction table